# PHP: Writing a If statement that can determine file types

Tags: php, html, database

So I am writing a program that has many files but only 2 categorizes. The webpages themselves but are .php files and .php files that go into a "includes" folder that are not html documents.

I want to say again for clarification, **both** files are .php, but only some have html documentation and the other files have only strictly php information, such as building tables or connecting to the database.

I was wondering how I could write a If statment, that would basically say:

If (Has HTML information then this is true or okay){Run code}
Else (Don't run this code)

The question is, how do I get PHP to identify which files has HTML documentation, such as locating a body tag or a HTML tag?

The issue i'm having is I have ajax setup and its running my code on ALL queries so I need to be able to differentiate them to stop it from running all the time. I only need this particular piece of code to run when I am connected to a page that has HTML documentation.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$DB = "grocery";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $DB);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: ".$conn->connect_error);
}
else if (){
  echo "<div class='dbMessage'>You have successfully connected to [$DB] Database.</div>";
}
```

Comment: If it's possible for you to determine that all system file would have the same string in the name - a much simple approach would be read all files and "slice" it that way

Comment: You really seem to be going about this back asswards. You should separate your code into templates/output and non-output related files, e.g. in separate folders. This is about *separation of concerns*. Look into MVC. Also, things like a failed database connection should cause PHP to simply die through an exception or `exit(1)` call, which then causes the *web server* to output an error page. Don't mix your error handling into your happy path.

Comment: Put the portion of code that must run in your "HTML" files in a file which you will include only where it is required.  Dont include unrequired code in all your files.  I always put `.php` on php only files, and `.phtml` on combined files.